# Why does this Javascript example copy the variable value instead of pass by reference?

Tags: javascript, pass-by-reference

In **Javascript The Good Parts**, it states:

[image]

So I would expect the following code example to output **1001** since "objects are never copied but passed around by reference", so why does it output **0000**?

```
var page_item = {
  id_code : 'welcome',
  title : 'Welcome',
  access_groups : {
      developer : '0010',
      administrator : '0100'
  }
};
page_item.access_groups.member = '0000';
var member = page_item.access_groups.member;
member = '1001';

$('p#test').html(page_item.access_groups.member); //should be "1001" but is "0000"
```

## Added:

@Gareth @David, thanks, this is what I was trying to show in this example, works:

```
var page_item = {
  id_code : 'welcome',
  title : 'Welcome',
  access_groups : {
      developer : '0010',
      administrator : '0100'
  }
};
var page_item2 = page_item;
page_item2.access_groups.developer = '1001';

$('p#test').html(page_item.access_groups.developer); //is '1001'
```

Comment: This is the same in Python, and easily explained there (`x.y = ...` is a method call on `x`'s `__dict__`, `x = ...` is not a method call). @Potential answerers: Is there a similar reasoning in JS?

Comment: @delnan - `x.y =` is not a method call in Javascript. (Well, it *is* possible in ECMAScript to define setter and getter methods for object properties but that's not the paradigm which caused the confusion in this question)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't think of pass-by-reference in the C++ context, because it's not the same.

```
var member = page_item.access_groups.member // Sets member to this value
member = '1001'; // Now sets it to another value
```

If there was a method on strings which changed them, then this:

```
member.removeLastLetter();
```

would alter `page_item.access_groups.member`. However, with your `=` you are changing the variable's reference, not the object it previously referenced

Comment: I was thinking about whether this is actually correct or not, and a key thing to note is that String is an object too. After I realized that, it made more sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

Because `page_item.access_groups.member` is a string and not an Object.

Comment: Even if `page_item.access_groups.member = {}`, a following line `var member = page_item.access_groups.member; member = {foo:1001}` wouldn't update the `page_item.access_groups.member` object

Answer (score 0):

This is probably getting bashed by JS-Gurus but basically it goes down like this:

Objects are passed by reference.
Strings (numbers, etc... basically 1 dimensional variables) are passed by value.

I did try and understand the lengthy explanations on data types but I seriously needed some work done and haven't gotten time to look at it more closely.

Comment: PBR and PBV are basically myths in javascript. The main point is, if you have a reference to **anything** (string or otherwise) in a variable `var x`, as soon as you write `x = ...` you are *discarding* your initial reference and creating a new one, as opposed to performing the an operation on the value you had previously referenced.